# using LEFT query not working

Tags: sql, database

I have this value in my `Open Date` column: `2017-6-14 AM 12:00:00`

I want to pick up just the date (`2017-6-14`) part, so I used `LEFT ()` in my query. Unfortunately, shows more than just '2017-6-14' in my results.

This is the query that I made.

```
Select a.Name, b.Restaurant, a.City, c.[Postal Code] as 'State', 
   LEFT(a.[Open Date],CHAIRINDEX(' ',a.[Open Date]-1)), 
   a.CO as 'T Date', 
   (SELECT Count(Taskid) FROM Tasks WHERE Complete = 'True' AND SID = a.ID GROUP BY SID) AS 'Tasks Complete', 
   (SELECT COUNT(Complete) FROM Tasks WHERE Complete = 'false' AND T_Date <= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) AND SID = a.ID GROUP BY SID) AS 'Tasks Overdue' 
FROM Stores a 
JOIN Concepts b ON a.ConceptID = b.R_id 
JOIN States c ON a.State = c.Stateid WHERE a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) 
ORDER BY a.[Open Date] ASC
```

Comment: Use a date conversion or formatting function. Don't try to take the LEFT part of a date. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: "Not working" is not descriptive.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @Jacob H Thanks for the idea, I solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left would've worked well if [Open Data] were type varchar but if it is datime then you can extract the date part only via conversion, for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [Open Date])
```

note: in any case, if [Open Date] is varchar then the the -1 should be after the first bracket:

```
LEFT(a.[Open Date],CHAIRINDEX(' ',a.[Open Date])-1)
```

Comment: It is a date time, and I use CONVERT(date, [Open Date]) but, it looks still same! 2017-6-14 AM 12:00:00 like this.

Comment: CONVERT(varchar, a.[Open Date], 101) I tried this one and it works! Thanks for the idea @Jayvee